# Can a quantifier be either a pronoun or an adjective?

Tags: grammar

1. A few people have already entered the room.
2. A few of the people have already entered the room.

In the first example, it seems to me that the quantifier "few" is acting as an adjective in front of the noun (and subject) people. In the second example, it seems that the quantifier "few" is acting as a pronoun and is the subject of the sentence. Is my assessment correct? Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes. See the [dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/few). It has both adjective, pronoun and noun definitions.